# Windows 7 Tagging

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Right now there are 3 Windows 7 tags, plus a synonym:

- Windows7 (synonym for Windows-7)
- Windows-7 (1265 tags)
- Windows-7-64 (43 tags)
- Windows7-32 (6 tags)

Should we merge the 32bit and 64bit tags into the Windows-7 tag? If not, at least cleaning up the formatting discrepancy would be helpful.

Comment: I think you could safely merge the two tags. There exist, already, the following architecture-specific tags: [64-bit](http://serverfault.com/tags/64-bit), [x64](http://serverfault.com/tags/x64), [32bit-64bit](http://serverfault.com/tags/32bit-64bit), [amd64](http://serverfault.com/tags/amd64), [x86-64](http://serverfault.com/tags/x86-64), [64bit](http://serverfault.com/tags/64bit), [32-bit](http://serverfault.com/tags/32-bit) and [win32](http://serverfault.com/tags/win32).

Comment: ... and most of those shouldn't exist either.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'd have just fixed if I ran into it on my own. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed; thanks for the suggestion!